# How much money would a soul cost?

Tags: magic, economy, modern-age

*Felryite* is a pale gemstone that can trap souls. Souls can be used as a powerful energy source. They can be used to extend the lifespan of a person by 100 years, to create a sentient AI and an über-powerful computing systems.

Only healthy souls can be used safely. Using corrupted and evil souls is very dangerous and the only use for evil souls is for weapon systems like hunter-killer drones and homing ammunition.

**How much money would a soul cost?**

*Felryite* is as rare as diamonds.

PS : Detecting corrupted or pure souls is easy. For example the souls of psychopaths and criminals are evil souls, while the souls of philanthropist people, who do good deeds, are pure. The souls of babies are pure too. *Felryite* works like a magnet, meaning anyone can trap souls with a chunk of *Felryite*.

Comment: This depends on who can use the magic to trap souls, if there are laws against this (making it illegal), if there is a chance that a soul escapes, how easy it is to detect that someone has a corrupted soul, how easy the extraction of Felryite is, how much you need, if the person still feels mental pain if her soul is used and many many more things. This is completely opinion-based and depends solely on what you think is appropriate as the authors. Choose whatever suits your needs.

Comment: Diamonds are cheap, common, and easily industrially manufactured, don't believe the hype.

Comment: Do trapped souls suffer?

Comment: As @Separatrix said, diamonds are [not that exclusive or rare](https://www.gemsociety.org/article/are-diamonds-really-rare/)

Comment: I think that's POB as asked.  How about something loke “how do I determine what the cost would be within the story?” rather than expecting someone to be able to state a specific price without guessing.

Comment: ... your question is a bit ambiguous and relies on other factors such as: the use/purpose of the soul within the body (is it just energy or the person's inner mind/self). Is it seen as morally wrong to trap and use souls? - are there laws against it? basically, the initial function of the soul, and how it is seen by the general populous both have large factors in the cost of an item

Comment: Why do people hate the questions of this guy? I love his questions!

Comment: @W.Myrmidon I don't think anyone hate the questions of Alex, it is just that this one is not really well formulated - it's highly opinion based in it's current shape and that's something one should [avoid in a question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @W.Myrmidon Who knows,Flying pigs? I should ask em lmao.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How much does a slave cost?

You can look up online how much slaves cost in the [antebellum South](https://www.measuringworth.com/slavery.php). Back in Roman or Ottoman times, where whole villages of recently conquered were enslaved, they were basically giving the slaves away to whoever wanted them.

Moral of the story, since a soul costs a life, then it depends on the value of life. In our own times, if you want the soul of a famous mathematician, the price trends towards infinity, since there aren't that many famous mathematician souls around. If you just want some peasant, you can probably get a soul for a few dollars in India or the Congo. Even in the linked article, you can see that slave/soul was worth 50% more if he was a blacksmith. So the price is going to depend on the scarcity of the person from whom the soul would be taken.